# Command to bash terminal in python

Tags: python, bash, command

I've used the methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output/9266901#9266901) answer to try to send "du -sch *" to the terminal but I get errors.

For example, when I use this:

```
out = check_output(["du", "-sch", "*"])
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_main.py", line 29, in test_sample
    out = check_output(["du", "-sch", "*"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['du', '-sch', '*']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The problem I get is due to the "*" because without it it works fine.

I've also tried:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["du", "-sch", "*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

But I get a different result than the one I get using the command directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output("du -sch *", shell=True)
```

More about [shell argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Comment: Or use just on sting instead of a sequence as recommended:

subprocess.check_output(["du -sch *"], shell='/bin/bash')